# Wierd GCC behaviour with ARM assembler. ANDSEQ instruction

Tags: gcc, assembly, arm

If I try to assemble this program:

```
.text
main:
 andseq r1,r3,r2,lsl #13
```

With the command `gcc -c test.s`, I get the following error:

```
Error: bad instruction `andseq r1,r3,r2,lsl#13'
```

After some tries I replaced `andseq` with `andeqs`, and now it compiles fine.

But if I dump the resulting obj file with `objdump -d test.o` I get this:

```
Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <main>:
   0:   00131682        andseq  r1, r3, r2, lsl #13
```

Note how the instruction is decoded as `andseq` ....

Am I missing something? Is this a bug?

My system is Raspbian GNU/Linux 8, and my gcc is: gcc (Raspbian 4.9.2-10) 4.9.2. I have also tested with gcc-8.1.0 (edit, not really see edit), same results.

EDIT:

In fact, it seems Im using the same binutils with gcc8, so I really only tested this `GNU assembler (GNU Binutils for Raspbian) 2.25`. I'll try a more recent assembler.

Comment: Sounds bug-ish if the assembler and disassembler disagree about what order the predicate vs. the set-flags option go.

Comment: I agree, but I is tough to believe for me

Comment: Yeah you'd think someone would have noticed by now, unless it's only broken in a specific version of the disassembler?  Did you try other versions of `objdump`, or `llvm-objdump`?  Also, did your gcc-8.1 install include an updated binutils?  Because gcc itself doesn't include an assembler at all, it relies on `as` from binutils.  (Even when you compile C, gcc actually generates a `.s` and runs `as` on it, or pipes it to `as`.)  So a different gcc front-end might not have been a useful test at all.

Comment: Could this be a difference between unified and split syntax?

Comment: @PeterCordes you are right, I didn't update the assembler itself, silly me. I'll edit the question. I'll try an updated assembler. I didn't try another objdump neither, I'll give that a chance. I tried gdb but I suppose it is using the same objdump.

Comment: @fuz I don't know, I dont know how to test that or how to force assembler to use ARM specific syntax... I'll investigate further. Thank you for the hint.

Comment: @fonkap Try a `.syntax unified` or `.syntax divided` to select the assembler's syntax (as indicated in the manual).  I don't see how you can set the syntax for `objdump`; perhaps one of them defaults to unified syntax (objdump?) whereas the other one defaults to divided syntax (as?)?

Comment: @fuz you are right with `.syntax unified` it worked. I wasn't aware I was using that modern unified syntax... it is a bit confusing that `as` and `objdump` use different defaults though. Relevant info here: https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/ARM-Directives.html | https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/ARM_002dInstruction_002dSet.html

Comment: @fonkap I suppose `as` defaults to divided syntax for compatibility whereas `objdump` was updated to unified syntax for programmer convenience as no compatibility is needed for `objdump`.

Comment: @fuz that makes sense. Thank you very much. If you want to write your comments as a response I will be pleased to mark it as correct.

Comment: this isnt strictly limited to unified syntax vs non-unified.  Just two different (sets of) folks wrote the code.  This isnt the first nor last time this will be seen for this or other instruction sets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For compatibility with old assembly files, GNU as defaults to *divided syntax* for ARM assembly.  In divided syntax, `andeqs` is the correct mnemonic for the instruction you desire.  You can issue a `.syntax unified` directive to select unified syntax, in which `andseq` is the correct mnemonic.

GNU objdump on the other hand only knows unified syntax, which explains the apparent inconsistency.

For new developments, I advise you to consistently use unified syntax if possible.

Answer (score 1):

There is a good UAL vs pre-UAL mnemonic table on [ARMv8](https://static.docs.arm.com/ddi0487/da/DDI0487D_a_armv8_arm.pdf) Appendix K6 "Legacy Instruction Syntax for AArch32 Instruction Sets"

One of the entries of that table is:

```
Pre-UAL syntax    UAL equivalent
AND<c>S           ANDS<c>
```

where `eq` is one of the possible condition codes `<c>`.